# Excel - Reference Value where multiple conditions are met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am finding it extremely difficult to translate a simple SQL Style Lookup into excel.

I have data spread about multiple excel sheets which I am trying to combine into one sheet/table automatically. The association can be done by combining multiple conditions and checking them against static results.

For example I am looking to reference the value for "heartrate" (column G in $ecg_interpretation_association) WHERE userid (column B in $ecg_interpretation_association) =1 AND is_vector (column D in $ecg_interpretation_association) =1 AND is_standard (column E in $ecg_interpretation_association) = 0 AND patientid=$A2

I have tried using the vlookup funktion and the & operator and have miserably failed at the syntax.

This is easily solved in mysql and I am certain excel can do this as well. Do you have any suggestions on how I should write my function?

current code (sverweis = german vlookup; wahl = german choice)

```
=SVERWEIS("110"&$A2;WAHL({1.4}$exam_ecg_interpretation_association.$B:$B&$exam_ecg_interpretation_association.$D:$D&$exam_ecg_interpretation_association.$E:$E&$A2;$G:$G);2;0)
```

Comment: See this post on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another